# JRE 1.6 garbage collection fails to terminate threads

Tags: multithreading, garbage-collection, upgrade, java-6

I've been developing my Java application on JDK6 and running under JRE 6 and 7. All worked fine.

I had to get myself a new notebook recently, so I installed latest NetBeans with JDK7 and set project configuration to "Source/Binary Format: JDK 6". The application compiles and runs well under JRE7.

Under Linux's default java-1.6.0-openjdk it behaves differently, though. It looks like 99% of threads are never terminated. I end up with an application having 1000+ threads, 100+ database connections, etc. Even simple operations (timer-based) leave the thread open.

In profiler (visualVM) I can request garbage collection, but it does not terminate threads, just clears some memory.

Anybody met such behavior?

Comment: Does your application have any log to track its activity? Like your threads activity.. Maybe its not releated to the JVM.

Comment: Sure, I know the activity pretty well. It's just that when I run same .jar on different JVMs it does or does not terminate threads.

Comment: Are u sue all are gc threads ? Did u look at thread dump ?

Comment: Probably these threads are from your application or some library.